# Ruby: Set ACL when sending PUT to S3 with Aws::S3::Presigner

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm presigning urls for PUT requests to S3 using Ruby's `aws-sdk` gem ([v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html)):

```
@presigner ||= Aws::S3::Presigner.new
url = @presigner.presigned_url(
  :put_object,
  bucket: 'images-dev', 
  key: 'my_file.png',
  expires_in: 60 * 60 * 24,
)
```

I'd like to set the uploaded file's acl to `public-read` as part of this process. Is that possible?

Any pointers would be very helpful!

Comment: Typically you can provide the same set of options as the underlying method supports, put_object in this case. Did you try the [#presigned_url(method, params = {})](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html#presigned_url-instance_method) option, passing a hash with bucket, key, expires, and acl.

Comment: I tried adding `acl: 'public-read'` to the params, despite the fact that I didn't see the `acl` listed in the documentation, and the acl was not set. All other params are working as expected. Do I need to use `whitelist_headers` or something else strange?

Comment: Ah I was reading (and actually mis-reading) the v3 SDK docs earlier. V3 appears to support whiltelist_headers (though I don't see it in v2) which I guess would allow "x-amz-acl": "public-read".